# Video Playing in horizontal list view

Tags: android, android-video-player, horizontallist

I am using horizontal list view https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView for showing video thumbnail using Adapter. Now i want to play video on every thumbnail, For this i inflated my custom video player and its working fine. But my problem is that when  i clicked more then one video then , all clicked video inflated view and start to playing video, My task is to play only one video at a time , if user clicked another video and previous video is playing then it should and play current video.

**My adapetr class is :**

```
public class VideoSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchVideoBean> {

public VideoSearchAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<SearchVideoBean> searchVideoUrls) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.videoList = searchVideoUrls;
        this.mcontext = context;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)              
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
         gesture = new GestureDetector(mcontext, new listnerOnVideo());
    }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return videoList.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userPic);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageview.setTag(position);
    // set user image
    holder.imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    String url = videoList.get(position).getVideoUrl();
    url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20").trim();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, holder.imageview, MainActivity.defaultOptions);

    holder.imageview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (alreadyplaying) {

                parent.removeView(parent.findViewById(R.id.bc_myvideo));
            }

            else{
            Log.i("ddd", "video not playing");
            imageParent = view.getParent();
            return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    catalog.findVideoByID(videoList.get(position).getVideoId(), new VideoListener() {

        @Override
        public void onVideo(Video video) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
    //      progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }
            }, 1500);

            tempVideoView.add(video);
            tempVideoView.start();
            alreadyplaying = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {

        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;

}

class listnerOnVideo extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) (imageParent);

            View v2 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.brightcove_video_view, parent);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(holder.imageview.getWidth(), holder.imageview.getHeight());
            tempVideoView = (BrightcoveVideoView) v2.findViewById(R.id.bc_myvideo);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v2.findViewById(R.id.pBarinMain);
            tempVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            tempVideoView.requestLayout();

            tempVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    parent.removeView(parent.findViewById(R.id.bc_myvideo));
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ee) {
            Log.e("ddd", ""+ee.getMessage());
        }

        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i solved this on my side anyone need code then comment here

Comment: i want to play videos in horizontal list view like snapchat.. does your code work for this.